# Laravel: path to directory being repeated twice in call to method

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to queue a Laravel job that will dispatch another job to the queue.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\HE;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use App\Models\HE\HECentral;
use App\Jobs\HE\ProcessAvailabilityUpdate;

class QueueAvailabilityUpdates implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        foreach (HECentral::all() as $practice) {
            // add them to the queue
            logger($practice);
            dispatch(new ProcessAvailabilityUpdate($practice));
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason the path to 'ProcessAvailabilityUpdate' is being duplicated. From the logs:

```
local.ERROR: Class "App\Jobs\HE\App\Jobs\HE\ProcessAvailabilityUpdate" not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class \"App\\Jobs\\HE\\App\\Jobs\\HE\\ProcessAvailabilityUpdate\" not found at /Users/mydocs/Documents/GitHub/new-api/app/Jobs/HE/QueueAvailabilityUpdates.php:34)
[stacktrace]
```

I've tried using `use ProcessAvailabilityUpdate;` instead of `use App\Jobs\HE\ProcessAvailabilityUpdate;`, and `dispatch(new App\Jobs\HE\ProcessAvailabilityUpdate($practice));` without success.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: 1. check your ProcessAvailabilityUpdate class directory path is correct
2. run this command `php artisan queue:restart`

Comment: Thank you, the second option fixed it. It was strange, other changes were having effect in the code, but not the path.